# Removing duplicate of immutable types in memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management

I looking for easy way to automatic removing duplicated of immutable types for save memory (Use the same object by reference).

For example: `code 1` and `code 2` doing the same work, but `code 1` using about 200 Mb, and `code 2` only about 6 Mb.

There any solution for this? Memory managers or something else?

Code 1 (about 200 Mb):

```
a = []
for _ in range(100000):
    a.append('my immutable data' * 100)
```

Code 2 (about 6 Mb):

```
a = []
my_string = 'my immutable data' * 100
for _ in range(100000):
    a.append(my_string)
```

I can use `sys.intern()` for string. But I also interested in other immutable types like `tuple`.

One of solutions:

```
class InternElements:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__elements_dict = {}

    def intern(self, element: Any):
        try:
            return self.__elements_dict[element]
        except KeyError:
            self.__elements_dict[element] = element
            return element

    def extend(self, elements: Iterable[Any]):
        for element in elements:
            self.intern(element)
```

Comment: I am not sure how your code example is relevant to the question (if I get it). In your example 1, you are creating different strings (hence creation of 100000 string) and in the another you are referencing same string. It is obvious that there will be difference in the memory usage

Comment: Thanks! But what about other types? For example `tuple`?